# Error flume MorphlineSolrSink readJson java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS

Tags: flume, cloudera-manager, morphline

I am trying to read json from avro source and sink to Solr.
When I tried `readLine {}` and stored as string it worked.
But when trying `readJson{}` it throwing following error.

Version : 
CDH 5.9.0, Parcels

## Error

```
2017-01-26 06:35:38,604 ERROR org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Unable to start SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@513a4842 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } - Exception follows.
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit>(JsonInclude.java:204)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:44)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:558)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:483)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.json.ReadJsonBuilder$ReadJson.<init>(ReadJsonBuilder.java:88)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.json.ReadJsonBuilder.build(ReadJsonBuilder.java:55)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.buildCommand(AbstractCommand.java:307)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.buildCommandChain(AbstractCommand.java:254)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdlib.Pipe.<init>(Pipe.java:46)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdlib.PipeBuilder.build(PipeBuilder.java:40)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:126)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:55)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineHandlerImpl.configure(MorphlineHandlerImpl.java:101)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineSink.start(MorphlineSink.java:98)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
        at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

## Flume Config :

```
agent.sources = AvroSource
agent.channels = memorychannel1
agent.sinks = solrSink

agent.channels.memorychannel1.type = memory
agent.channels.memorychannel1.capacity = 10000
agent.channels.memorychannel1.transactionCapacity = 200

The avro source
agent.sources.AvroSource.type     = avro
agent.sources.AvroSource.bind     = 0.0.0.0
agent.sources.AvroSource.port     = 4344
agent.sources.AvroSource.channels = memorychannel1
agent.sources.AvroSource.compression-type = deflate

agent.sinks.solrSink.type = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineSolrSink
agent.sinks.solrSink.morphlineFile = /home/flume/morphline.conf

agent.sources.AvroSource.channels = memorychannel1
agent.sinks.solrSink.channel = memorychannel1
```

## morphline.conf

> SOLR_LOCATOR : {   collection : testCollection   zkHost :
>   "192.168.21.31:2181/solr" }
>
> morphlines : [   {
>       id : morphline1    importCommands : ["com.cloudera.**", "org.apache.solr.**", "org.kitesdk.**"]
>
> ```
> commands : [
>     # read the JSON blob
>   {  readJson: {}  }
>   {
>     extractAvroPaths {
>       flatten : false
>       paths : {
>         id : /id
>         type : /type
>         name : /name
>         address : /address
>       }
>     }
>   }
>
>   {
>     sanitizeUnknownSolrFields {
>       # Location from which to fetch Solr schema
>       solrLocator : ${SOLR_LOCATOR}
>
>       # renameToPrefix : "ignored_"
>     }
>   }
>
>   # load the record into a Solr server or MapReduce Reducer.
>   {
>     loadSolr {
>       solrLocator : ${SOLR_LOCATOR}
>     }
>   }
>  ]   } ]
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is from jackson-annotations library.
**The USE_DEFAULTS enum constant was added in 2.6**
[image: Screenshot from jackson-annotation document]
And CDH 5.9.0 has old version of jackson-annotations.
[image: CDH jar list]
Add new Version to fix problem.